# Solve the given initial-value problem Using Elimination method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Need help with the following:

$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}  &= −5x − y \\
                \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}  &= 4x − y \end{align*}$$

With initial conditions: $x(1) = 0, y(1) = 1$

I converted it into

$$\begin{align*} (D+5)x+y &= 0\\
              -4x+(D+1)y  &= 0 \end{align*}$$

And got the solutions $x(t) = c_1e^{-3t} + c_2te^{-3t}$ and $y(t) = c_3e^{-3t}+c_4te^{-3t}$.

I tried to substitute into the first equation and solve for $c_3, c_4$ in terms of $c_1, c_2$ but I must have done something wrong as I am not getting the correct answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you have too many constant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By elimination we should have

$$x'=-5x-y\implies y=-x'-5x \qquad y'=-x''-5x'$$
 $$-x''-5x'=4x+x'+5x \implies x''+6x'+9x=0\implies x(t) = c_1e^{-3t} + c_2te^{-3t}$$

and then from $y=-x'-5x$ we have

$$y(t) = 3c_1e^{-3t}  +3c_2te^{-3t}-c_2e^{-3t}-5c_1e^{-3t}  -5c_2te^{-3t}=(-2c_1-c_2)e^{-3t}  -2c_2te^{-3t}$$

thus we can find $c_1$ and $c_2$ by initial conditions.